# retrofit Give kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

Data get from the Sql server and get data json. this json data parsing retofit2. 
 Created Login Activity but its give error

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    internal lateinit var api : APIInterface

    private var compositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable? = null

    var userName : String? = null

    var password : String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {

            userName = tvUsername.text.toString()
            password = tvPassword.text.toString()

            getUserName(userName!!,password!!)
        }
    }

    fun getUserName(user : String, pass : String){


        val retrofit = APIClient.apIClient
        if (retrofit != null) {
            api = retrofit.create(APIInterface::class.java)
        }
        compositeDisposable!!.add(api.getLoginData(user, pass)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    if (it.success.equals(1)){

                    val intent = Intent(this,Company::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Login Successfully!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(this,"UserName or Password is Wrong!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                },{
                    Toast.makeText(this, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                })
        )
    }
}
```

when Debbuger reached on compositeDisposable!!.add(api.getLoginData(user, pass) it's give Error kotlin.kotlinNullPointerException

RestApi Url :

```
http://localhost/Account/Login.php?user=ABC&pass=1
```

APIClient.kt

```
object APIClient {
   val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/Account/"
    var retrofit:Retrofit? = null
    val apIClient:Retrofit?
        get() {
            if (retrofit == null)
            {
                retrofit =  Retrofit.Builder().
                        baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .build()
            }
            return retrofit
        }


}
```

APIInterface.kt

```
interface APIInterface {
 @GET("Login.php")
    fun getLoginData(@Query("user") user : String,
                     @Query("pass") pass : String) : Observable<LoginList>
}
```

Comment: Well you never initialized `compositeDisposable` then force-unwrapped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause for the `NullPointerException` is that `compositeDisposable` is `null`.

At the beginning of `MyActivity` that variable is initialised to `null` and then it's never changed, so when you use the `!!` operator the exception is thrown.
I think you can initialise `compositeDisposable` directly with the correct value, i.e. something like `val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()`.

Also, `val` should be preferred over `var` whenever possible – as immutability is easier to control – and `userName` and `password` could probably be local variable or at least `private`